# Infinispan cache objects not expiring

Tags: infinispan

Following is remote cache setup for one of the applications;

1. Remote cache: Infinispan deployed in Openshift environment (Hotrod
   protocol), no eviction strategy defined.
2. lifespan of a given object (let's say X) in cache is 10 seconds.
3. this object (X) is accessed every 5 seconds using the key it's stored
   in cache.

Will object (X) expire after 10 seconds of lifespan or not - since the same object (X) may be accessed just before lifespan ends?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, lifespan will expire an entry after the given time frame irrespective of reads performed on it. If the value is updated then the expiration time will also be updated respectively.

If you wish for an entry to only expired after 10 seconds of not receiving read accesses, you should be using max

Comment: in our case we are seeing a different behavior i.e. cache object is not expiring after 10 seconds, its taking close to 60 seconds before the older object in cache is replaced with new one against a particular key.  
**cache.putAsync(key, responseVO, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);** is being used to put element in cache and **cache.get(key)** to retrieve it.  Updated object is returned if I change frequency of accessing object in cache to 10 seconds instead of 5 seconds and for any value (access frequency) lower than 10 seconds older object is returned.

Comment: How are you validating it is expired? The entry should be expired, however it will not be removed until it is accessed or the expiration reaper runs to remove it. The reaper by default runs every minute btw.

Comment: Actually I am using Postman to call one REST API that first checks in cache for a given key, if found - its associated value is returned otherwise values is fetched from DB and put in cache. If API is called iteratively in every 5 seconds stale data is returned (API keeps on returning stale data for 60 seconds) and if API is called every 10 seconds good data is returned. I've verified API is not caching.

Comment: I would suggest logging an issue to https://issues.redhat.com/projects/ISPN/issues with a simple reproducer then. Because what I have said in the answer is the expected behavior.

Comment: I'll proceed as advised. Thanks.